# How do I transfer messages from iPhone to Android like Samsung Smart Switch and Google transfer?

Tags: android, ios, swift, iphone, kotlin

I want to build an app to transfer message history between iOS and Android.

Apple does not allow third party apps to access messages, but **Samsung Smart Switch** circumvents this by using either phone-to-phone USB connection or by accessing iCloud. Google phone transfer seems to do a similar thing.

How do these apps make this possible and is this something third party developers can do?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can transfer things over like that from Android to Apple iPhone unless they give you the option when you are first setting up the iPhone to transfer contents over from android and it also transfers the messages.

Another option though it's been a long time since I have used an Android device. You could use something like https://messages.google.com/web to load up your android messages from your phone and possibly just export them and save them to your computer.

As for developing such a tool, working within the messages API for apple. I think you can only develop extensions or addons but can't directly access the content for security reasons. Without further research, the companies might be only allowing the company to do this via a contract between them, but would not let a 3rd party vendor such as you or I access this data.

https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/

Nowhere in the guidelines does it specify that you can't access the SMSes. But you can only access it if you use private methods which are not allowed and will get your app rejected.

You can only access data for which Apple supplies a documented API. You can not access files outside of the Sandbox of your App unless Apple provides an API for it.

Comment: Thanks for the response. To add on, there seems to be some way third party developers are mimicking the connection to iTunes to backup messages, because there are other pieces of software using this method of migration or backup like MCE Content Transfer, Dr.Fone, iCareFone, etc. They pop up with the same "Trust this device" prompt on the iPhone when connected to iTunes, similar to Samsung Smart Switch when wired. I couldn't find any documentation on this either.